# Derive direction in which a spot light emites its light from a projection matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, lighting

First of all, sorry if my question sounds too basic or even makes no sense. I'm new with game development

I'm working with [HPL1Engine](https://github.com/FrictionalGames/HPL1Engine), specifically, the lights parts. I need to know the direction in which a spot light emits its light. But [the class that represents a spot light](https://github.com/FrictionalGames/HPL1Engine/blob/master/include/scene/Light3DSpot.h#L48), doesn't have any direction vector.

So, I've been reading about lights in 3D engines, and I've detected in the class some other properties that I consider important. Like a projection matrix and angles (FOV and aspect). I'm trying to focus on the projection matrix ([here](https://github.com/FrictionalGames/HPL1Engine/blob/master/sources/scene/Light3DSpot.cpp#L147), how the engine calculates it), but I'm not sure if I'm wasting my time.

Again, my goal is to know the direction in which a spot light emits its light (a vector), but I just have this matrix, and many other properties I don't relate with the spot direction calculation.

How could I know this direction from which I have (what the class provides me)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the view matrix of the class (looks like you can retrieve it via GetViewMatrix()). Take a vec4 that points in the "default direction" (0 0 -1 most likely), e.g. (0 0 -1 0) and multiply it by the view matrix. This should give you the direction of the spot light in the x y and z components of the vec4.

This is assuming, though, that the view matrix here actually does what I assume it does, which is to shift the coordinate system such that its new z axis through the origin lines up with the "middle ray" of the projection cone.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the direction from the **view** matrix. The view matrix contains the axes of the spot light: the first collumn contains the x-axis ("side" vector), the second collumn contains the y-axis ("up" vector), and the third collumn contains the z-axis ("forward" vector). So grab the x, y and z values from the third collumn, and there you go. Depending on the coordinate system, you may need to negate the value, as per **TravisG**'s answer.

Comment: Seems to work. As you both sent the same message, I mark the first one as response. But many thanks!